# Unicode chars shown as decimal numbers instead of symbols, how do I fix this?

Tags: c++

I want to write a small program that is able to display unicode characters not included in ASCII or LATIN_1 using wchar_t.

I'm using C++14 and I've configured my text editor to store characters according to the UTF-8 standard. I've tried using both char16_t and char32_t but the result stays the same.

---

inside main()

```
wchar_t spade = L'\u2660';
wchar_t heart = L'\u2665';
wchar_t diamond = L'\u2666';
wchar_t clover = L'\u2663';

cout << spade << endl;
cout << heart << endl;
cout << diamond << endl;
cout << clover << endl;
```

---

The code above outputs the decimal values 9824 9829 9830 9827, instead of the unicode character symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::cout` does not have any overloads of `operator<<` that accept `wchar_t`, `char16_t` or `char32_t` as input. So the compiler promotes those values to `int`, which is why you see numeric values outputted.

You need to use `std::wcout` instead of `std::cout` when outputting `wchar_t` data.

Alternatively, if your console supports UTF-8, you can use `std::cout` with UTF-8 strings, instead of wide (UTF-16/32) strings.

```cpp
const char *spade = u8"♠";
const char *heart = u8"♥";
const char *diamond = u8"♦";
const char *clover = u8"♣";

cout << spade << endl;
cout << heart << endl;
cout << diamond << endl;
cout << clover << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use std::wcout to print Unicode characters